# How to Restrict access to fields in a database

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

In a database (Microsoft Access, Relational), is it possible to restrict access to a specific field in a table for a certain group?

So the group would have access to the table but not see one of the fields?

If not, is the only way to do this by seperating the data into another table and restricting it for this group?

Comment: What database are you referring to?

Comment: Edited original post

Answer (score 0):

You can not restrict access to a specific field.

However, you can create a query based off a table.  And you can also set a table's "Visible" property to "No".  This isn't foolproof; if the user knows how to change the properties of a table then they can change it back to "Visible".

There really is no 100% foolproof way to lock down an Access database entirely.  However, you can make it awfully difficult by hiding the objects, hiding the database and bypassing the CTRL key (to avoid the old Shift/CTRL trick).

Answer (score 0):

You can create different views for difference users | users group with only required columns that they should allow to access. Then grant permission for users/user groups on those views accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).